# Fastest way to update column value

Tags: mysql, performance, update

I need to set all values of a given column `foo` to a constant varchar `bar`. Is there a faster way to do that than with the vanilla `UPDATE mytable SET foo = 'bar'`?

Facts:

- This is an Oracle MySQL 8.0.20 server (via `SELECT @@VERSION`)
- This table uses the InnoDB engine
- The column is not part of any index
- The column datatype is `varchar(2000)`.
- I can't change the datatypes
- I have full access to the server and could manipulate the `.idb` files directly, if necessary.
- The largest table has ~1.7mi records and the regular update takes ~30mins
- Memory, CPU and storage doesn't seem to be a bottleneck, so far (checking `iotop` and `htop` itself)

*Note: I need to do similar updates to multiple columns in multiple tables, but what I describe here applies to them all, except for the datatype, which is the worst case (all the other columns are also `varchar`, but not that long).*

Comment: What is your criteria of efficiency? What's wrong with a simple update?

Comment: how many rows do you have. All solutions take time

Comment: Updated the title and more facts. My focus is execution time. Sorry for not being clear in the first place.

Comment: Please post TEXT results from MySQL Command Prompt for query  SELECT @@VERSION;  so we know the specific version you are using.

Comment: Comments addressed (cc @Akina @Wilson)

Comment: *The largest table has ~1.7mi records* What is the table size (or avg record size)? Anycase the update woth the rate ~1000 rows/second seems a norma. PS. Test the time for `create new_table like old_table; insert into new_table (col1, col2, ..., col_to_alter, ...) select col1, col2, ..., 'new value', ... from old_table;`

Comment: @Akina, do you think dropping the column and adding back with `bar` as default value could be any faster?

Comment: No. I doubt that this operations chain will be performed ONLINE, not COPY. I simply try to understand what part of the operation load is data re-arrange.

Answer (score 0):

Changing 1.7M rows in a table requires making copies of all the rows that are changed.  (This is in case there is a crash or `ROLLBACK`.)  The system is not designed to handle huge changes like that.

It *may* be faster to do the `UPDATE` in chunks, `COMMITting` after each chunk.  This way the undo stuff is not huge.

I discuss techniques for walking through a table via the `PRIMARY KEY` in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks .  That blog is worded in terms of `DELETEs`, but `UPDATEs` can use the same techniques.

Side notes.  Some of these may lead to other solutions.

Do not even think of touching the `.ibd` file.

You do have a `PRIMARY KEY`, don't you?  If not, that is bad.  And it makes the "walking" that I describe less efficient.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the actual `UPDATE` if you want to discuss things further.

In general, it is "bad schema design" to need to change every row of a large table.  There are much more efficient techniques.  One that comes to mind is to have a second table that contains only one row -- with the current value of `foo`.  However, it may or may not work for your use case.

What is your use case?  Do you change *all* the rows?  Or does that `UPDATE` usually change only a few rows?  How many different values?  Is it a flag, a date, or what?  Etc.

You have `VARCHAR(2000)`; is the contents typically large?  How big is the typical record?  These questions lead into discussing "off-record" storage of large columns.

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  What is the table size (`SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mytable';`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Rick. You got a bunch of questions there, and I will try to address those as soon as possible, but, for now, I can tell you that this is not a regular process. I need to share this data with folks not privy to the content of some columns, thus this is like a "redaction" process. In fact, `bar` is, in most cases, just `redacted`. Any chance I could skip the logs and make things faster? I understand I may have issues in case of a crash.

Comment: @tavlima - Changing table/column names -- sure; losing datatypes -- not wise; "simplifying" the query -- may lead to solving the wrong problem.  It is not possible to skip the undo/redo logs.

Answer (score 0):

> I have full access to the server and could manipulate the .idb files directly ...

No, you *really* couldn't.

```
Database != File
```

All you would achieve is *completely breaking* your database.

All DBMSs, not just MySQL, store their data files in proprietary, binary formats that mean *absolutely nothing* to the likes of you or me.

Let the database to worry about *its* own files and only ever make changes through the DBMS.

Comment: Yeah, @Phill, I'm aware of that. I just brought that up because I have seen tools that would need that kind of access (like some Percona CLI tools, for instance).